# SecurityException NFC permission required

Tags: android, permissions, nfc

I have been doing some NFC development on android, and I have hit a brick wall. I launch the app and it immediatly fails with a "Unfortunately,..... has stopped working".

Some quick googling showed I need the put the permission in the manifest. I did that, but lo and behold, I still get the same error!

Here is the start of my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
    <!-- rest of the file --->
```

And the output in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {za.co.fnb.ms.nfcreader/za.co.fnb.ms.nfcreader.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10253 nor current process has android.permission.NFC.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think You have to declare the uses permission at the top of the Manifest, outside the application tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to activities which you use nfc:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.example.CLASSNAME"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>  
            <data android:mimeType="mime/type" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_type"/>   

    </activity>
```

And also you have to define permissions before application tag.

Comment: There were a few comments, Opiatefuchs was first in the comments, followed by Burak. Since I can only upvote comments and accept answers. I am accepting this one. The other were all correct though.

Comment: @Gerrie I didn't understand your clarification about this accept?? Can you be clear??

Answer (score 3):

`<uses-permission>`, `<uses-sdk>`, and `<uses-feature>` go *outside* the `<application>` element:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsware.android.jimmyb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.secret/agent.man"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/NFC/SecretAgentMan))

Answer (score 2):

The section

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
```

Needs to be outside of your application tag.

---

Like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
...
```

Read [***Structure of the Manifest File***](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct)