# "Unfortunately MyAPP has stopped working" possible due to NFC permissions

Tags: android, nfc, manifest

I am trying to develop and NFC app and I have hit a brick wall. I launch the app and it immediately fails with a "Unfortunately,See (my app) has stopped working".

I believe it is a manifest issue as in logcat, it says,

```
"Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.see/com.example.see.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: NFC permission required: Neither user 10197 nor current process has android.permission.NFC."
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.pemission.NFC" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.See">


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SecurityException NFC permission required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847366/securityexception-nfc-permission-required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>` instead of
**pemission**